# Sending data to the clicked url via AJAX/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, url

I can't seem to send data to the link that I click on. All I'm getting is an undefined index in my php file.

```
<a href="output.php"> Click me </a>

('a').click(function(){


    href = "output.php";

    $.post( 'output.php', { output: "hello"},
         function( data ) {


     window.location = href;
     }
     );

     return false;
  });
```

The ajax successfully sends, but the page redirected to the output.php page with errors saying the index "output" doesn't exist.

```
<?php

$content = $_POST['output'];
echo $content;



?>
```

Help anyone? This is so confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It's because output.php is being loaded twice: once on your Ajax request, and once when you change window.location.

The second time, there's nothing in $_POST, because the browser isn't making a post request at that point.

ADDED FOR CLARITY:

If you use Firebug, and take out the window.location line, you should see the Ajax request go out and the response from the server.

Comment: thanks for clarifying, but is there a way to get it to load to the page while sending the ajax?

Comment: That's not really how Ajax works. Ajax makes a request to output.php. At that time, $_POST has your value in it. When you echo that, the response does go to the browser, but you have to do something with it in your success call back.

Try this:
Remove the window.location statement, or just comment it out. Replace it with:

`console.log(data)`

In your console, you will see what you echoed back from the server.

Comment: Well is there any possible way around this? I'm just trying to send text/string to the link that I click on

Comment: output.php could in theory be an entire page. You could even do `$(body).html(data)` in your success call back. Or just put the content into a <div>.

Comment: I think I know what you're explaining... basically load content from output.php replacing the current content without changing the url at all? Thanks for all the help btw.

Comment: I'm wondering if you really want or need to use Ajax at all. Why not write a simple form to send data to the server?

Comment: I would use a form with hidden content, but this is pulling data from a wordpress plugin and it generates too many html tags for me to really wrap a form around it without making things complicated

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I'm still not sure what you're trying to do, or how the code you posted relates to it. But if you want to send data to the server via Ajax, and then have the browser load output.php and display that data, you could do something like this:

In your PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST["output"])){
    $output = $_POST["output"];
    echo $output;
} elseif (isset($_GET["output"])){
    $output = $_GET["output"];
    echo $output;
}
```

In your success callback:
      `window.location = href + "?output="+data`

Answer (score 0):

try this :

Demo.php

```
<html>
    <head>
            <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a").click(function(){

                    $.post( 'output.php', { output: "hello"},function( data ) {
                            $("div").append(data);
        }
        );

            });
          });
    </script>
    <body>
            <a href="#">Click Me</a>       
            <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

output.php

```
<?php
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($_POST);
 echo "</pre>";
 exit;  
?>
```